# Show that $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2< 2y\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2< 2y\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The set can be expressed as $$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2< 2y\} \\
=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 -2y< 0\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+(y-1)^2 < 1\} = B((0,1),1)$$

and since open balls are open sets $A$ would be open. However I'm trying to use the metric to show this. If $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 -2y< 0\}$  and I let $(x,y)\in A$ and $B((x,y), r)$, where $r=\min \{|x|,|y|\}$. Now picking $(x',y') \in B((x,y),r)$ I would want to show that $B((x,y), r) \subset A$, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There might some problems with what you are trying... for example $(x,y)=(0,1)\in B((0,1),1)$
then $r=\text{min}\{|0|,|1|\}=0$ and the ball $B((0,1),0)=\emptyset\subset B((0,1),1)$. The radius should be positive.

Even for other points that $x\neq0$ will also have some issues, you can see this by drawing a point near enough to the line of circumference.

A solution could be achieved by setting $r=1-d((0,1),(x,y))$ where $d$ is the distance function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=(x,y)\in B_1 (0,1)$. If $r=d(P,\partial B_1(0,1))$, you can prove that $B_{r/2}(x,y)\subset B_1(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the basic fact that all open balls are open in the metric topology or use that $A = f^{-1}[(-\infty,0)]$ where $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -2y$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $(x_0,y_0)\in A$ and then choose $r\gt0:r\lt \min\{\sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2},1-\sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2}\}$. 
For any $(x',y')\in B((x_0,y_0),r), (x'-x_0)^2+(y'-y_0)^2\lt r^2 $

By triangle inequality,

$\begin{align}
\sqrt {x'^2+(y'-1)^2}&\le \sqrt{(x'-x_0)^2+(y'-y_0)^2} + \sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2}\\
                     &\lt r+\sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2}\\
                     &\lt (1-\sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2})+\sqrt{x_0^2+(y_0-1)^2}=1\\
                   &\implies (x',y')\in B((0,1),1)\implies  B((0,1),1)\subset B((x_0,y_0),r)\end{align}$.